# complexity analysis of kth smallest element in min heap

Tags: algorithm, heap

I am working on to find the `k`th smallest element in min heap. I have got a code for this whose complexity is `O(k log k)`. I tried to improve it to `O(k)`.
Below is the code.

```
 struct heap{
      int *array;
      int count;
      int capacity;
 };

 int kthsmallestelement(struct heap *h,int i,int k){
      if(i<0||i>=h->count) 
         return INT_MIN;
      if(k==1)
        return h->array[i];
      k--;
      int j=2*i+1;
      int m=2*i+2;
      if(h->array[j] < h->array[m])
      {
         int x=kthsmallestelement(h,j,k);
         if(x==INT_MIN)
            return kthsmallestelement(h,m,k);
         return x; 
      }
      else
      {
           int x=kthsmallestelement(h,m,k);
           if(x==INT_MIN)
                return kthsmallestelement(h,j,k);
            return x;
      }
 }
```

My code is traversing `k` elements in heap and thus complexity is `O(k)`.
Is it correct?

Comment: The Frederickson algorithm solves this, but it is way more complicated, and probably has huge constant factors: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540183710308

Comment: No, your code is NOT traversing any elements, so it has no complexity.

Comment: Why are you decrementing k immediately before declaring and assigning k again ? Why does kthsmallestelement have 3 arguments, and you call it with only 2 ?  Does this code even compile ?

Comment: @gen-y-s No, it doesn't. It fails as soon as the `struct heap` declaration, which lacks the terminating semicolon (not to mention the function type `int`, which was glued to the function name until I inserted the space). That's why I said the code does NOT traverse anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your code, and in fact, its entire approach - are completely wrong, IIUC.

In a classic min-heap, the only thing you know is that each path from the root to the children is non-decreasing. There are no other constraints, in particular no constraints between the paths.

It follows that the *k*-th smallest element can be *anywhere* in the first *2<sup>k</sup>* element. If you are just using the entire heap's array built & maintained using the classic heap algorithm, any solution will necessarily be *Ω(min(n, 2<sup>k</sup>))*. Anything below that will require additional requirements on the array's structure, an additional data structure, or both.

Comment: You can use the binary heap's structure for O(klogk) solution, by creating a new min-heap, place the head in it (with pointer to the actual element), and for k steps: extract the top, and insert its two children instead. This is done in O(klogk) since the heap never grows more than `k` elements, and each operation is logarithmic in its size, giving a solution more optimal than the lower bound you mentioned, for k << n

Comment: If I remember correctly, I've also seen an O(k) solution, but that was way too complex for me to remember what's going on.

Comment: @amit Is it the article referenced in the comment by Niklas B.?

Comment: Yes seems like it. And of course, the "trivial" O(klogk) solution

Comment: @amit If *k* is known in advance, then there's a trivial O(1) solution as well, no? Just use a combination of a heap and a balanced tree restricted to size *k*. Modifications are still *log(n)*, and lookup is O(1).

Comment: I need to go through it again then, but the O(klogk) does not need to know k in advance.